# Laravel: Count through has many and output as array

Tags: arrays, laravel, relationship

I made google chart and here is my code:

Controller:

```
$settlements = Settlement::where('town_id', Auth::user()->town_id)
  ->where('reon_id', '1')
  ->get();
```

View:

```
@foreach ($settlements as $settlement)
     [
       '{{$settlement->name}}',
        {{$settlement->members->count()}},
        {{$settlement->members->where('cipher_id', '0')->count()}},
     ],
 @endforeach
```

and that gives me a nice chart with number of member in each settlement and one sam bar where cipher_id == 0. And that works fine.

Now I need a count of how many each settlement has a members as an array. I try sam thing like this but all in my controller:

```
$settlements = Settlement::where('town_id', Auth::user()->town_id)
  ->where('reon_id', '1')
  ->get();

foreach ($settlements as $settlement) {
  $sett = $settlement->members->count();
}
```

but this output only number of one settlement how many members that it have. (sorry for bad english)

I need an array of all settlement.

And maybe this is wrong approach because I plan to make one more array where where cipher_id == 0 and then calculate a percentage of all that numbers. For example:

First array:

256
148
312

Second array:

100
58
211

So result will be:

39.0625
39.18918919
67.62820513

I hope I explain good why I trying this way to get count. What's the solution of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`withCount()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) method to count relations:

```
$settlements = Settlement::where('town_id', Auth::user()->town_id)
    ->withCount('members')
    ->where('reon_id', '1')
    ->get();
```

It will add `members_count` property to each `Settlement` object.

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models):

> If you want to count the number of results from a relationship without actually loading them you may use the `withCount` method, which will place a `{relation}_count` column on your resulting models

Of course, you can use your way, but in this case, you need to load the data first to avoid N+1 problem:

```
->with('members')
```

And then count members:

```
foreach ($settlements as $settlement) {
    $sett[] = $settlement->members->count();
}
```

Also, this will load all members into memory. If you don't want that, use the `withCount()`

Comment: Yes, this is the thing that I looking for. Thanks @Alexey Mezenin ;) just one more thing... How to get the same thing but with cipher_id == 0 where cipher_id is in other model (not Settlement model), in table where counting is actually going on?

Comment: @NenadM in this case, use a closure. For example, `->withCount(['members' => function($q) { $q->where('cipher_id', 0); }])`

Comment: $sett[] = $settlement->members->where('cipher_id', '0')->count(); What about this?

Comment: @NenadM yes, you can do that too, but `withCount()` is a way better solution.

Comment: One more thing and then I will let you go :) how to do percentage of each of this numbers and output as array again?

Comment: @NenadM if I understood you correctly, you may count all members and then use `map()` or `transform()` collection methods to iterate over a collection and counting percentage of members for each group. Or you could just do that in a view with something like `{{ $settlement->members_count / $totalMembers * 100 }}%`

Comment: I need in controller, not in view. For example: $percentage = round(($sett_members[] / $sett[]) * 100,1);

Comment: Use `map()` or `transform()` then.